# How to convert an integer to string in Assembly 8086

Tags: string, function, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to create a function that gets a parameter in hexadecimal and a char*.
I am trying to turn the parameter to a string and then append it to the char*.

This is my code:

```
wordToString PROC
    push bp                 
    mov bp,sp
    
    xor cx,cx
    mov bx, 10
    
    loop1:   
    mov dx, 0     
    mov ax, [bp+6]
    div bx
        
    mov [bp+6][cx], dx
    call print_al_chr
        
    inc cx   
    cmp cx,4 
    jle loop1
    
    
    mov sp,bp 
    pop bp   
    ret 2

    
wordToString ENDP

main:
    lea dx, array
    mov ax, num1
    
    push dx
    push ax  
    
    call wordToString
```

Comment: You forgot to describe your problem. Also, you did not comment your code and you did not use a debugger. Hell, you haven't even fixed the syntax errors.

Comment: I have a problem and I need your help to fix it. I don't know what are my syntax errors. @Jester

Comment: there is no addressing mode with `[bp+6][cx]`. Does this code actually assemble?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> mov ax, [bp+6]
> ```

The parameter *num1* was pushed last and thus is closest to the return address on the stack available at `[bp+2]`. Therefore you need to write `mov ax, [bp+4]`
Also you retrieve this value within the loop and thus you'll end up with 5 identical divisions. Move it to before the loop **and make sure you don't modify `AX` other than by the `div` instruction**.

---

> ```
> ret 2
> ```

You pushed 2 words on the stack, and so you need to remove 4 bytes upon returning. Write `ret 4`

---

> ```
> mov [bp+6][cx], dx
> ```

This can't be a valid instruction!
You need to fetch the pointer to the array **before** starting the loop and then within the loop you increment this value.

```
;Before the loop
mov  di, [bp+6]
...
;Within the loop
mov  [di], dl            <<< Use DL, a byte in the range [0,9]
inc  di
...
inc  cx
cmp  cx,4 
jle  loop1               <<< Does 5 iterations because of JLE
                         <<< For 4 iterations you would use JL
```